# What is the most ideal, cross-language method of executing an A/B split?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, math, coding-style

I'm on a project where I have to implement an A/B split in 15 or so views, in this case for PHP - we'd like to use the same math if possible for our JavaScript projects.

What is the most ideal, least verbose, least CPU-intensive way of doing this? For this project, I just need to set a variable: something like:

```
// In the main controller
if(rand(1, 2) == 2)
{
    $recipe = 'program';
}
else
{
    $recipe = 'standard';
}
define('RECIPE',$recipe);


// In the view
$program = (RECIPE == 'program') ? '&ProgramOfInterest=' . $program_id : '';
```

We have 20 or so devs here and we all have our ways - what is the best, benchmark-proven way?

Comment: How about `i%2`, or rather `1&i` which is faster (yes, I'm joking) :)

Comment: @hakre - you know how there's never a true 'random' in programming. It's all just calculations and algorithms, some random calculations have odds which favor a certain outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) over `rand()`. It's 4x faster than `rand()` because `mt_rand` uses a [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) over the libc random number generator which `rand()` uses (see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)).

You can then get an equivalent to `mt_rand()` for javascript from the [php.js library](http://phpjs.org/functions/mt_rand:476).

Answer (score 2):

least cpu-intensive way:

- use a image sensor (ideally a CMOS) to take a very long exposure of black.
- You'll get lots of truly random noise due to light interference and sensor heat
- the bits in the uncompressed image will be completely random

A team got something like 200Gb/sec of random data like this :)

Then simply:

```
var counter = 0;
if(imageBit[counter++]){
```

:D

Comment: Wow. Funny comment *and* funny answer.

Comment: it's a perfectly valid answer!  It's not verbose, it's ___very___ non-CPU intensive and unlikely any normal algorithm it's truly random, making it "ideal"  :D

Comment: Yes, but it is very memory unefficient to get the bits of the image data in an array you can read this way.

Comment: no it's not, you just need to optimize it.   Make sure the image is stored non-fragmented on disk or in memory and then do a direct read to a specific address.  You can cache a bit of data (say 64 bytes) so you don't need to do reads very often.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the A/B split needs to be consistent across all users, so a user should consistently fall in the A or the B bucket (if not, your analysis of the A/B buckets will not reveal any info related to page navigation).

Hence using a rand function is probably not what you want.

Instead use a session identifier, session cookie or persistent cookie, and simply use the last 3 bytes of that cookie instead of your random value.   You can add the bytes or multiply their ascii values to generate a number which you can the use as your cut-off.

This would be very portable across PHP and JS, and it is cheap in CPU and easy to verify correctness in a unit test.